# Figure out which process forks too many threads

Tags: process, monitoring, troubleshooting, ulimit

I have a process in a Linux installation that at some point has some kind of spike and passes the max allowed number of threads/processes allowed by the system. I found this by checking `ps -elfT | wc -l` repeatedly.

But what I don't know is what exactly is it that causes this spike.
The output of `ps -elfT` has a lot of information, but I cannot easily understand if there is some child process that does some kind of "blurp" in forking and makes a mess.

How could I figure that out?

Example: `ps -elfT | cut -d' ' -f3 | sort |uniq` gives me the processes running at the time. How could I add a count to see how much each contributes to the total?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ps -eo nlwp,pid,args --sort nlwp
```

Would show a list of processes sorted by their number of threads.

For a top-like view of that, you can always do:

```
watch -n 1 'ps -eo nlwp,pid,args --sort -nlwp | head'
```

Or you could use... `top`.

- press <kbd>f</kbd> to select the fields to display.
- locate `nTH` (the number of threads) and press <kbd>d</kbd> to *display* it and <kbd>s</kbd> to make it the *sort* order
- you can adjust its display position with <kbd>→</kbd> and then <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>⏎</kbd>.
- <kbd>q</kbd> to get back to the process list
- press <kbd>H</kbd> if you want to see all the threads.
- <kbd>d</kbd> to adjust the delay.
- <kbd>?</kbd> for help.

Comment: Would I see for all users? And also would that show also threads like with the `T` in the command in my post?

Comment: How can I view this information constantly instead of running it constanly? I.e. keep it refreshing like top?

Comment: @Jim, see edit.